# Rectangular output for ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting

The Function ListContourPlot generates by default an output which has a square size. I would like to produce a rectangular output for example {1000,100}. ImageSize doesn't work because it shapes only the frame (the plot still has size {100,100}).

Thx,
rainer

Comment: Can't you trim you input data ? This works for instance `ListContourPlot[Flatten[Table[{i, j, i^2 + j^3}, {i, 1, 1000, 10}, {j, 1, 100, 10}], 1]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is `AspectRatio` what you are looking for?

```
ListContourPlot[Flatten[Table[{i, j, i^2 + j^3}, {i, 1, 1000, 10}, {j, 1, 100, 10}], 
  1], AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it is;-) Thx

Comment: ...or `AspectRatio -> Automatic`...